# py.test session level fixtures in setup_method

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to somehow use pytest fixtures from conftest.py in a test class's **setup**?
I need to initialize an object when the session starts and use it in some test classes' setup.

Something like this:

```
# conftest.py:

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def myfixture(request):
    return "myfixture"
```

---

```
# test_aaa.py

class TestAAA(object):

    def setup(self, method, myfixture):
        print("setup myfixture: {}".format(myfixture))

    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can do it directly. However, you can decorate the whole class with [`pytest.mark.usefixtures`](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#using-fixtures-from-classes-modules-or-projects), if that helps:

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures(['myfixture'])
class TestAAA(object):
    ...
```

IIRC, `setup_method` will be called before any of the automatically applied fixtures.

You can also utilize [`autouse`](https://pytest.org/latest/unittest.html#autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures) for class-level fixtures like so:

```py
class TestAAA(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def init_aaa(self, myfixture):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second option - but setup_method was called before init_aaa. So I replaced setup_method with setup (which is called before each test method in the class) and it worked. Will edit my original question.

Comment: @adi I think you can just replace `setup` entirely with `init_aaa` method which will have `autouse=True`, would this work?

Comment: in my case I need both (I want to create a base class for all tests that provides "myfixture" and let whoever inherits from this base class to decide on his/her setup method)

Answer (score 5):

I used this kind of a setup for a test class with pytest<=3.7.0 (it stopped working with pytest 3.7.1 release):

```
# conftest.py:

import pytest

# autouse=True does not work for fixtures that return value
# request param for fixture function is only required if the fixture uses it:
# e.g. for a teardown or parametrization. Otherwise don't use it.
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def myfixture():
    return "myfixture"
```

---

```
# test_aaa.py

import pytest

class TestAAA(object):
    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, myfixture):
        self.myfixture = myfixture

    def test_function1(self):
        # now you can use myfixture without passing it as param to each test function   
        assert self.myfixture == "myfixture"
```

Comment: This doesn't run.

Comment: @Neil thanks for the comment! I just tested it and it looks like this setup stopped working with pytest 3.7.1 release.
This setup only works with pytest<=3.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

For the example provided above, the object returned from the fixture can be set as an attribute of the test class. Any methods of this class will have access.

```
# test_fixture.py

import pytest

class TestAAA():
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def setup(self, myfixture):
    TestAAA.myfixture = myfixture

def test_function1(self):
    assert self.myfixture == "myfixture"
```

or if you inherit from `unittest.Testcase` you can do the following

```
# test_fixture.py

import pytest
from unittest import TestCase

class TestAAA(TestCase):
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, myfixture):
        self.myfixture = myfixture

    def test_function1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.myfixture, "myfixture")
```