# pyspark fixture not passed to setup_method when using pytest/conftest.py

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest

I am trying to create a test dataset to unit test some spark functions (in this case, test that my **get_spark_table** method returns only 2 rows).

Here is my **conftest.py** file:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", name='spark')
def spark() -> SparkSession:
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Testing").getOrCreate()
    yield spark
```

And the **test_your_class.py** file:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

class TestYourClass(): 
    """ 
    Test suite for YourClass functionality.
    """

    def setup_method(self, method, spark): 
        """ 
        Setup method that runs before each test method
        """

        py_data = [(1, "John"), (2, "Jane"), (3, "Bob")] 
        py_schema = StructType([
            StructField("id", IntegerType()), 
            StructField("name", StringType())]) 
        py_df = spark.createDataFrame(data = py_data, 
                                      schema = py_schema) 
        py_df.createOrReplaceTempView("people") 

   def get_spark_table(self, spark, tablename):
       query = f"SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE id > 1"     
       df = spark.sql(query) return df 

   def test_get_spark_table(self, spark):
       """ 
       Test SQL query
       """ 
       df = self.get_spark_table(spark, tablename = "people") 
       assert df.count() == 2
```

However, when I execute:

```
retcode = pytest.main([".", "-vv", "-k", "TestYourClass"])
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: setup_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'spark'

I have tried different options for the fixture/adjusting the conftest.py file and also creating the Spark session inside the test_your_class.py file. Creating the Spark session inside the test file works, but I would like to define the Spark session in **conftest.py**.

Answer (score 1):

`setup_method` is called before any applied fixtures are set up. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37437320/8075127)

You can create class-level fixtures instead to set up:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import pytest

class TestYourClass(): 
    """ 
    Test suite for YourClass functionality.
    """

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def init_spark_data(self, spark): 
        py_data = [(1, "John"), (2, "Jane"), (3, "Bob")] 
        py_schema = StructType([
            StructField("id", IntegerType()), 
            StructField("name", StringType())]) 
        py_df = spark.createDataFrame(data = py_data, 
                                      schema = py_schema) 
        py_df.createOrReplaceTempView("people") 

    def get_spark_table(self, spark, tablename):
        query = f"SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE id > 1"     
        df = spark.sql(query) 
        return df 

    def test_get_spark_table(self, spark):
        """ 
        Test SQL query
        """ 
        df = self.get_spark_table(spark, tablename = "people") 
        assert df.count() == 2
```

Comment: The suggestion you made works, but what is the difference between your init_spark_data() method, and the setup_method() I used. From the pytest documentation, I understood it as saying that the setup_method() would be evoked before any tests, and therefore should achieve a similar affect to your init_spark_data() + the autouse=True. What am I missing? 

This is from the pytest documentation: 
"Method and function level setup/teardown - Similarly, the following methods are called around each method invocation"(https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/xunit_setup.html)

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it looks like `autouse=True` is not required (I could be wrong). 
`setup_method` is *invoked* for every test method of a class *not before any tests*.
fixture's can use fixtures unlike the classic xunit-style setup. The documentation says there are many reasons why you should use fixtures instead of the classic xunit-style setup.